# Add text on UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I have just stepped in developing iOS App and it would be my honor to get answers from you guys. I want to add text on UIImage as this link

[image]
I'm not sure it's kind of text what else. Could you please tell me or this question had been asked please give me the link? I tried to google it many for hours but couldn't find the solution.

Thanks!

Comment: you just need to add a uilable on top of the image.

Comment: Just put the UILabel on top of your UIImage. Make sure on the document outline that it is actually on top.

Comment: @IdanMagled Is it that easy? I used to try that way but it didn't work.

Comment: is, it that easy :) 
just look if its on top of the image or the image is on top of the label.
if its worked - mark up so we will post the answer.

Comment: mark the comment up - so it will help others. @user3849461

Comment: @user2548635 can say that I'm not smart enough, but I don't know how to mark up the answer. Could you please tell me? I never use ask question before.

Comment: @user2548635 I can't see that

Comment: hover over it and you will.

Comment: @user2548635 still not. I think I don't have enough reputation, am I right?

Comment: @user2548635 https://www.dropbox.com/s/mv40sbh0a0l9xos/Screen%20Shot%202014-08-09%20at%209.59.09%20PM.png

Comment: Yeah I think you need at least 15 rep to do that. I will up vote @IdanMagled comment for you.

Answer (score 0):

Put `UILabel` in front `UIImageView`

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOURIMAGENAME.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];
[label setText:@"YOU TEXT"];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Test it and see how easy..